# First modules and "Unexpected token {"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to write my first module program and on the first step I get the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {".

```
//headerScript.js
const printHeader = (tekst) => {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    header.innerHTML = tekst;
};
export { printHeader };

//mainScript.js
import { printHeader } from "./headerScript";
printHeader("Hi");
```

Comment: What are you using to run the JS program?

Comment: Seems like you are running the code in an environment that doesn't understand module syntax. Please provide more information.

Comment: I use IDE Webstorm and i run in console and i open my project in chrome browser

Comment: If you *just* open a JS file in Chrome then it will show the source code. How are you loading it? Are you writing a browser extension? Are you using an HTML script element? What attributes are you using on that element?

Comment: Which file and which line are specified in the error message? Your code shows three `{` and it would be very helpful to know on which one we need to focus most.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\portfolio\ver 0.1\js\mainScript.js"
C:\Users\user\Desktop\portfolio\ver 0.1\js\mainScript.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { printHeader } from "./headerScript";
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Node doesn't understand module syntax by default yet.